# Google app signing, multiple apps and OAuth client ID:s for Google API:s issue

Tags: android, oauth, signing, clientid

Have apps registered and in production in google play console with package `a.b.c` and `a.b.d.`  I'm using Google Play App signing for both apps.

I'm using a Google play service and therefore need an Oauth 2.0 client ID to access the Google API. I've registered a client ID for `a.b.c` in Google API Console and interfacing the service for `a.b.c` app using the fingerprint from Google Signing Cert. This is working fine and I can use the services from a.b.c.

The problem is that I also need to interface the services from a.b.d - app. When I try to create the OAuth client id for a.b.d with my Google Play signing cert (shared with a.b.c) I get an error:

> "The fingerprint you specified is already used by an Android OAuth2 client ID in this project or another project".

So, is this a design flaw / limitation for using Google Play App Signing and is there any way around it exept depublish my app (a.b.d) and republish it not using Google Play App Signing?